# Chat getting disconnect automatically after some time (Android)

Tags: java, android, session, chat

The following code i am using for connecting to session and sending or receiving message.In logcat the last expression is register and unregister.

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        synchronized (sessions) {
            for (final OmegleSession session : sessions) {
                // In case anybody tries to run blocking operations ._.
                service.execute(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        session.checkEvents();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // uh
        }
    }
}
```

Getting this error in console not more than this :

```
[2015-09-22 11:38:12 - ddms] null
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:200)
at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.movePacket(JdwpPacket.java:235)
at com.android.ddmlib.Debugger.sendAndConsume(Debugger.java:347)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.forwardPacketToDebugger(Client.java:698)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:344)
at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

Following class i am using for the whole process if i does not use runnable in every section i does not get any response :

```
public void chatWaiting(OmegleSession session) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mTxtStatus.setText("Connecting...");
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void chatConnected(OmegleSession session) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mTxtStatus.setText("Stranger Connected :)");
                        //  System.out.println("You are now talking to a random stranger!");
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void strangerStoppedTyping(OmegleSession session) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                mTxtStatus.setText("Stopped typing!");
                        }
                    });
            }
            @Override
            public void strangerTyping(OmegleSession session) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                mTxtStatus.setText("");             
                mTxtStatus.setText("typing...");
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: That's completely normal, if your mobile phone enters in sleep mode it will probably disconnect from the Internet 4 a while.

Comment: no actually when i put sleep time to more than 30000 or more then it does not disconnect but chat messages goes slow so how to fix it thanks

Comment: Maybe a logging statement in the `catch` clause would bring some more information.

Comment: SubOptimal@ what do you mean . please i am fresher can you ask in bit details thanks in advance

Comment: oh i understand you right know ok wait i have to post that catch clause logging statement here ok

Comment: Couldn't it be that you simply exhaust your resources? From the code it looks that you in an infinite while-loop create for each session a new Runnable and this again and again.

Comment: SubOptimal@ Yes you are saying right, i have uploaded class below in which every process running inside ui thread. But if i does not use that app does not get message or any response

Comment: `BufferOverflowlException` is not a client disconnect. What are you talking about?

Comment: Actually after do chat for sometime the chat disconnects automatically. if i set eventparsedelay time to more than 5000 , chat does not disconnect but chat response very slow... its thread sleeping problem...